# SARIMA+GARCH model

Tags: time-series, programming, garch

The model ARIMA+GARCH writing as this form with the rugarch package in R:

```
spec=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)),
                            mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(2,1)))
```

**My Question:** How to write in case if the model SARIMA+GARCH in R?

Where SARIMA model:

`Model <- Arima(data,order=c(2,1,2),seasonal=list(order=c(1,0,0),12))`

Comment: So... at the end, how did you solve it? Did you use SARIMA residuals into the GARCH specification with armaOrder=c(0,0) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "rugarch" package in R, you can include these terms via the argument `external.regressors` within the argument `mean.model` in the ugarchspec function.

**From CRAN**:

`external.regressors` A matrix object containing the external regressors to
include in the mean equation with as many rows as will be included in the data
(which is passed in the fit function).

For further reference: https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I don' think that works because SARIMA does not contain external regressors. SARIMA is actually an ARIMA with coefficient restrictions. I am not aware of an R package that allows estimating SARIMA+GARCH models.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fit SARIMA model residuals into the GARCH specification with armaOrder=c(0,0)